# How can we have concept of multiple schemas in Coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, schema

In Sqlite we can create multiple schemas based on the users login or based on some other logic. How can we achieve similar concept in iOS app with CoreData framework.
My iOS App has multi user login. I want to have offline usage for what ever users using the app by logging in. Similar to schema in SQLite where data wont get added in same tables, I am looking for similar one in Core Data.

Comment: You can have as many dat models as you like. What specifically do you need to do?

Comment: @TomHarrington, I updated my description. Hope it helps

Comment: It sounds more like you want different data depending on the user, not multiple schemas. It's hard to tell though.

Comment: @TomHarrington, Yes you are right different data obviously based on the user. I don't want to use some IDs to track the relationships etc. If a user logs out, just delete the schema and everything associated with him will be wiped out.

Comment: @Satyam data model files are equivalent of database schemas in Core Data framework. Data model files are created during development and I have never seen created on the fly during runtime. However the data associated with a data model file which have sqlite extension could be deleted and created during run time. so you can define all the needed schemas, and then for each user save them into a separate sqlite file, and then delete or created sqlite files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to have per-user data is to remove all user data when someone logs out. `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` has a method called `destroyPersistentStore(at:ofType:options:)` which is designed to do exactly that. It will remove all files associated with a specific persistent store. When using this method you'll need to be careful to not keep any in-memory references to anything that was fetched from that store, because they won't work anymore and will almost certainly crash the app if you try to use them.

On a related point, this does **not** mean having multiple schemas and deleting the schema, as you mention in a comment, doesn't make sense here. In Core Data, the data model serves a similar purpose to a relational database schema. It defines the classes and relationships that can exist in the model but it does not contain the actual data. This is the same idea as a [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema), which define the tables and so on that can exist in the database but which are not the same thing as the data.